# What is the meaning of ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty

Tags: c#, .net

While I was implementing a `ICustomTypeDescriptor`, I stumbled across the `GetDefaultProperty` method. I have just implemented making use of `TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty` and then I just wondered: I actually have no clue what this method's intended purpose is. I'm guessing the property a person is the most likely to edit first, such as `TextBox.Text` but I can't really seem to confirm that idea.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.getdefaultproperty(v=vs.100).aspx) isn't helpfull in any way in that regard, stating:

> Returns the default property for this instance of a component.

The documentation says returning null is for objects without properties. So what if one would make a say a ICustomTypeDescriptor for a 3d Box class, something along the lines of:

```
public class Box {
    public double Length { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
}
```

What property should I use?

Answer (score 0):

This method returns the equivalent of *[DefaultPropertyAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultpropertyattribute)*. It is not really precisely specified what a default property (or event) should be, but your guess matches the common usage: when there is a single property the user is most likely interested in, it can be marked in this way, for example see *[PrintDocument](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e55c908229e36f99a52745d4ee85316a0e8bb6a2/src/libraries/System.Drawing.Common/src/System/Drawing/Printing/PrintDocument.cs)* (its name) or *[Timer](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/912b04dfd1efea3b0b3ad7586cf73c5d7ffc0c1c/src/libraries/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter/src/System/Timers/Timer.cs)* (the interval).

It is actually fine to return `null` if there is no applicable method; the framework does so in a couple of places anyway.